# PS script [ref] works on some computer and not others

Tags: powershell

I wrote a powershell script for one of the companies I support (when I say wrote, of course I mean harvested most of it from the internet and modified it).  It shows a folder selector and you pick a folder with word docs and it will convert them to PDF, keeping the name.  I wrote and tested this all on W10, and when I went to deploy it to a couple of users using W7, it had issues.  I upgraded their PS version to 4, and on the first computer, that solved it and it works flawlessly.  On the second one, after the update, it started complaining about this line

```
 $doc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref] $wdFormatPDF)
```

with the following:

```
Argument: '1' should not be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Do 
not use [ref].
At C:\Users\----\Desktop\word2pdf.ps1:50 char:2
+  $doc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref] $wdFormatPDF)
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RefArgumentToNonRefParameterMsg
```

It says Do not use [ref], so I remove it and it works.

```
$doc.saveas($path, $wdFormatPDF)
```

Go to the third one and bring along the newly modified script, update PS and now I get the opposite message:

```
Argument: '1' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].
```

Add it back in and it works fine.

My question is what the heck is going on here?  I'm fairly new to PS but I've done some other programming and I know the difference between passing a var by reference and by value.

Comment: If you've found the cause/solution, please post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I was hoping for some confirmation that this is indeed the answer, though it does seem likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As soon as I posted it, I thought of the probable answer. I checked and sure enough the 2 that require ref are office 2010 and the one that does not want it is 2007.

Comment: OP added the quote into the original post. I've moved it into answer